# Node.js - Sequelize ORM - Simple CRUD(Create, Read, Update and Delete) example

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, crud

After searching for a simple example for implementing CRUD code using latest Sequelize ORM version 4.15, couldn't find the answer in a single question. Had to search for each CRUD operation separately.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CRUD using Node.js and Sequelize ORM:

Example using simple Organization entity with "id" and "name" fields.

1. app.js

   `...
    var organizations = require('./routes/organizations');
   ...`

2. routes/organizations

```js
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('organization', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
            tableName: 'organization'
        });
};
```

3. routes/organizations

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const sequelize = require('path/to/sequelize');
const Model = sequelize.import('../models/organization');

/* GET Models. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var code = 500;
    var message = 'Internal Server Error';
    var result = '';

    var page = req.query.page || 1;
    var limit = req.query.limit || 5;
    var offset = (page - 1) * limit;

    Model
        .findAndCountAll({
            offset: +offset,
            limit: +limit
        })
        .then(result => {
            code = 200;
            message = 'OK';

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    data: { models: result }
                }
            });
        });
});

/* GET Model. */
router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var code = 500;
    var message = 'Internal Server Error';
    var result = '';

    var id = req.params.id | 0;

    Model
        .find({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        })
        .then(result => {
            code = 200;
            message = 'OK';

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    data: { model: result }
                }
            });
        });
});

/* POST new Model. */
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var code = 500;
    var message = 'Internal Server Error';
    var response = '';

    var postData = {
        name: req.body.name
    };

    Model.create(postData)
        .then(function (model) {
            code = 200;
            message = 'OK';
            response = 'Record is successfully added.';

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    msg: response
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            code = 500;
            response = message;

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    msg: response
                }
            });
        });
});

/* PUT old Model. */
router.put('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var code = 500;
    var message = 'Internal Server Error';
    var response = '';

    var id = req.params.id;
    var putData = {
        name: req.body.name
    };

    Model.update(putData,
        {
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        }
    )
        .then(function (model) {
            code = 200;
            message = 'OK';
            response = 'Record is successfully updated.';

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    msg: response
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            code = 500;
            response = message;

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    msg: response
                }
            });
        });
});

/* DELETE Model. */
router.delete('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var code = 500;
    var message = 'Internal Server Error';
    var response = '';

    var id = req.params.id;

    Model.destroy(
        {
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        }
    )
        .then(function (deletedRecord) {
            if (deletedRecord === 1) {
                code = 200;
                message = 'OK';
                response = 'Record is successfully deleted.';
            } else {
                code = 404;
                message = 'OK';
                response = 'Record not found.';
            }
            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    msg: response
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            code = 500;
            response = message;

            res.json({
                code: code,
                message: message,
                response: {
                    msg: response
                }
            });
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

It would be much appreciated to know a better code than the above. It could help someone.

Comment: Checkout this npm module I created, it might help. https://github.com/DiegoRBaquero/express-sequelize-crud-router